# How do you use the replace method properly?

Tags: python, replace

```
phone_numbers = {"John Smith": "+37682929928", "Marry Simpsons": "+423998200919"}
```

Loop over the phone_numbers values and in each loop print out the phone number,
but with 00 instead of the +.  In other words, your code should output:
0037682929928
00423998200919

```
new_phonenu=[]
for num in phone_numbers:
    new_phonenu = str.replace("+","00")
    new_phonenu.append(str)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Tried to format your post correctly. Please format code as code, text as text. And please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [one-line for loop](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/python-single-line-loops) to iterate through and perform an operation on each element in a list really quickly.

```
phone_numbers = {"John Smith": "+37682929928", "Marry Simpsons": "+423998200919"}

new_phonenu = [num.replace('+','00') for num in phone_numbers.values()]

print(*new_phonenu)
```

Output:

```
0037682929928 00423998200919
```

Edit:
If you want to include the keys, use

```
phone_numbers = {"John Smith": "+37682929928", "Marry Simpsons": "+423998200919"}
new_phonenu = {k:num.replace('+','00') for k,num in phone_numbers.items()}
print(new_phonenu)
```

Comment: How do I included the keys as well?

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic compact way (keeping non-starting-with-plus numbers):

```
new_phone_numbers = {p:('00'+n[1:] if n[0]=='+' else n) for p,n in phone_numbers.items()}
```

Pythonic compact way (not keeping non-starting-with-plus numbers):

```
new_phone_numbers = {p:'00'+n[1:] for p,n in phone_numbers.items() if n[0]=='+'}
```

More classic way - please uncomment last two lines if you want to include the numbers that don't follow the criteria of not starting with `+`:

```
new_phone_numbers = {}
for p in phone_numbers:
  t = phone_numbers[p].strip() # trim whitespaces at begging and end
  if t[0]=='+':
    new_phone_numbers[p]='00'+t[1:]
  #else:
    #new_phone_numbers[p]=t
```

Middle `+` are left untouched on purpouse, it is changed only when in the beggining.